# How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers while writing into excel with php and pear

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, scientific-notation

I am using pear package with PHP writing data into Excel sheet from mysql.
    In mysql   table I am having a column with named EAN. Its value is a 13 digit number. 
    When I try to run the program remaining all columns data is displaying correctly, 
    but this 14 digit number is displaying like a scientific notation 4.04623E+12.
    Original number is 4046228004518. I am using the below line of code.

```
$worksheet->write($i, 2, $sel_row['EAN']);
```

Comment: Yes it is working but by default it is showing with all hash symbols like ###########. After double click on the cell it shows original number.

Comment: Well it depends whether your PHP to Excel engine can also write formatting info into cells. Excel allows numbers as long as 15 decimal digits so values you pass are not affected. They are just displayed like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing an apostrophe (`'`) before value. It will force Excel to display value as text and thus not convert it to scientific notation.

Comment: it is showing '4046228004518 like this, after generating this excel sheet they need to upload this excel sheet into another database so that should not work with single quote.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with spring & apache poi.
This solution worked for me -

```
XSSFCellStyle numeric = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
numeric.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0"));
cell.setCellValue([large number]); //4046228004518
cell.setCellStyle(numeric);
```